# how to get your hands on output of cfdocument

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, cfdocument

Here is some simple cfdocument code  (reppath is set in Application.cfm):

```
<cfset xx = "let">
<cfdocument format = "pdf" name = "let" filename = "#reppath#/#xx#.pdf"         overwrite = 'true' >
Here is some stuff

</cfdocument>

<cflocation url = '#xx#.pdf'>
```

Original question  (was answered) : Now -- how do I display it and/or store it as a file?  I've been all over the internet looking for an answer to this simple question.  So far I've found very little -- lots of info on all the ins and outs of cfdocument, but no info on how to pick up the results.  The few hints I've found do not work.

Current question: This code now both opens the document and stores it as let.pdf.  However, when I attempt to open let.pdf in the document viewer I get this message.  I'm using Linux/Ubuntu.

[image: unable to open]

It opens fine in Firefox.

Comment: add the filename - <cfdocument filename="path/file.pdf" format = "pdf" name = "let">

Comment: Well, it put the file where I want it, but it locked it up.  I'd like to specify no locking of any kind, but I can't find a way to do that in the documentation.

Comment: Without the filename = it is supposed to display in the browser, but it doesn't.  i think that must be because it is locked.

Comment: are you sure its supposed to display it in the browser? i've never used it like that, i create the pdf and then let people download it (or it gets emailed etc)

Comment: any clue about how I prevent it from getting locked

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of "locked" ? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: will have to redo it -- back to you shortly

Comment: Okay, I have a screenshot of the problem.  Where do I upload it?  The problem occurred trying to open it in document viewer.  It opened fine in firefox, and when I saved what was displayed that opened fine in document viewer.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51428715/edit) your question and use the rich text editor buttons to embed the image.  Side note, using the "name" attribute means you want to store the pdf content in a variable (not display or save it to a file). To display it in a browser, remove the "name" attribute. To save it to a file, remove the "name" attribute and add the "filename" attribute.

Comment: I don't understand the use of cflocation. If you're trying to generate a file download, try this instead - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964/how-do-i-turn-a-coldfusion-page-into-a-pdf-download  Using `value="attachment;filename=fileNameHere.pdf"` forces a save-as dialog, and `value="attachment;filename=fileNameHere.pdf"` opens it in the browser window (if supported).

Comment: sorry, I think the cflocation was a test for something else, and I just swept it up when I rewrote the question.

Comment: Try the exact example on the other thread. What's the result?

Comment: @Ageax.  I'm finding the name = with or without the filename = sometimes displays the results and sometimes not.  Perhaps that is due to my version of Ubuntu?  Anyway, I found that javascript window.open displays the output -- and in another window which is good for me -- but it does require that I provide a name.  With or without a name=, with a filename = <cfdocument creates the file, and so far is putting it where I said.  I presume your "other thread" is questions 73964?  I couldn't figure out what code to try.

Comment: Try [this simple example](https://trycf.com/gist/8bc42a1de81e24db03bd4f4ff3dc96e7/lucee5?theme=monokai) first.  (You won't be able to run it from trycf.com, due to security restrictions.) Instead, save the code as testPage.cfm on you server. *Don't change anything*, just load the .cfm page in your browser. It should display a standard "Save As" or "Open File" dialog.  After you confirm it works, we can move on to calling the download page from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for this example.  It worked fine on my local system.  I certainly do need download code.  In my application I save the files for the user, and provide an opportunity to add more info in my homemade directory.   But I do mean to give them a way to download it.  Your tip on picking up the file from elsewhere would be appreciated.

Comment: All you need is to add a hyperlink on a separate page. The link should point to testPage.cfm. When the link is clicked, it'll display the "Save As/Open File" dialog.