# Open a .php file from .cfm file results to "Not Found" error

Tags: php, html, coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I create a new website using `CFML` and `Lucee` as server (through `Commandbox`).

In the past I used a `php` extension for creating a `pdf` file (with styling).

So I tried to open that `.php` file from within a `.cfm` file:

```
<a href="./pdf/print_pdf.php"><button>print pdf</button></a>
```

But it always results in a empty page (with the title "Error") telling me:

> Not Found

The `path` is correct, I double checked that, also I have access to any other file in the same  folder, just the `php` files don't work.

Is there something that I need to do before I can use php files that way?

I know, sooner or later it would be better to use a `coldfusion` extension or something to create that `pdf` file, but is there a easier/faster solution for now?

Comment: What happens if you put that link into a simple php page?

Comment: If I understand correctly, it sounds like you're not getting a 404 error on pulling up `print_pdf.php`,  It sounds like the error is within the php code itself trying to pull up a resource inside the php rendered pdf page not being found.  Is that correct?  If so, then this is not a ColdFusion issue and a php one instead.

Comment: Is PHP set up, configured and running on the server too? It won't work otherwise.

Comment: @haxtbh Shouldn't it just show me a file with the php code if its not set up, instead of throwing an error?

Answer (score 2):

Is your server/website set up to process both CFM and PHP files? The odds are no.

But the not found error seems more like the webserver just can't locate the file.

If you run your CF app under http://localhost:8000/index.cfm, can you put the URL to the PHP file in the location bar and get a response?

The path `./pdf/print_pdf.php` is telling the webserver to go up a folder from where the CFM file is located and then go forward from there. If the file is located at

```
http://localhost:8000/pdf/print_pdf.php
```

then change the path of the link to `/pdf/print_pdf.php` and see if it appears.

If it appears, it may just show the PHP code as plain text in the browser. If that happens, then your webserver just doesn't know what to do with PHP files.

I'd recommend just learning how to create a PDF with ColdFusion, it's pretty simple:

http://learncfinaweek.com/course/index/section/Document_Handling/item/cfdocument/

```
<cfdocument format="PDF">
<cfoutput>
Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet sirloin fatback #dateformat(now(), "short")#
</cfoutput>
</cfdocument>
```

Here's a little more info [from another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964/how-do-i-turn-a-coldfusion-page-into-a-pdf-download).

Comment: The path is correct, even a plain php file results in that error.

Comment: I think I start rebuilding my code now with cfdocument, so that I don't have to use php anymore, thanks :)